# ¿Cómo cancelo un merge subido a servidor en GIT?

Tags: git, git-merge

Hola estaba trabajando en un proyecto en una rama `features` y otro miembro del equipo hizo **merge** y unio con la rama `develop` el problema es que subio los cambios sin probar que todo valla bien. y bueno la pregunta es si se puede cancelar un merge que ya su fue subido, osea se hizo `commit`.

Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lo fácil:**
A veces es posible que desee deshacer un commit completo con todos los cambios. En lugar de pasar por todos los commit de forma manual, simplemente puede decirle a git que reviert un commit , que ni siquiera tiene que ser la última. Revertir un commit significa crear un nuevo commit  que deshaga todos los cambios que se hicieron en el commit incorrecto.

El comando es:

```
git revert dd61ab32
```

Donde **dd61ab32** es el identificador del commit.

**Lo dificil:**
Primero sincronizas el repositorio local con el repositorio en la "nube".
Usarás estos comandos en tu repositorio local

Para elegir la rama con el commit a revertir

```
git checkout [MI_RAMA]
```

Para sincronizarse al repositorio en linea

```
git fetch origin
```

Para obtener el historial:

```
git log
```

Obtendrás algo como:

```
commit 3368e1c5b8a47135a34169c885e8dd5ba01af5bb
commit baf8d5e7da9e41fcd37d63ae9483ee0b10bfac8e
```

Elige el commit donde tienes lo estable o por así decirlo antes de hacer el merge del que hablas, copia los primeros caracteres del commit por ejemplo: **baf8d5e**

Ahora para posicionarte sobre ese commit usas:

```
git checkout baf8d5e
```

A partir de aquí ya decides que hacer

Answer (score 2):

Para deshacer un merge puedes probar lo que que indica [este post](https://vabadus.es/blog/trabajando-con-git-deshacer-un-merge) (en 3 pasos): 
.

1. Lo primero, será localizar el commit al que se pretende volver, con el comando

   ```
   git log
   ```
2. Identifica el código del commit al que quieres volver
3. Entonces, solo habrá que lanzar el siguiente comando para dar marcha atrás:

   ```
   git reset --hard CÓDIGO_DEL_COMMIT`
   ```